# How to build a project using Crypto++ library in kdevelop

Tags: build, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, crypto++, kdevelop4

I wrote a small program that uses the `crypto++`library using `kdevelop` in `Ubuntu`. I get the output correctly when I compile it from the terminal using `-lcryptopp`. I would like to build and execute the program using the `cmake` from `kdevelop` itself. How can I include the `CRYPTOPP_DIR` in the `cmake configuration` for doing this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: I don't know about `kdevelop` and `cmake`, but Crypto++ supplies a `GNUmakefile`. You can see what files it compiles when building `libcryptopp.a` by issuing `make static`.  You can see what files it compiles when building `libcryptopp.so` by issuing `make dynamic`.  And you can see what files it compiles when building the executable by issuing `make cryptest.exe`.

Comment: Accordong to a tutorial I have executed `make static dynamic test` and then `cryptest.exe v`. Still building results in so many errors due to unknown `CRYPTOPP` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following piece of code to cmake file helped me:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(CRYPTOPP crypto++ /usr/lib) ## location of libcryptopp.so or libcryptopp.a
IF ( CRYPTOPP )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROGRAM_NAME} cryptopp ) ## Specifying cryptopp in uppercase gave me link error.
ENDIF( CRYPTOPP )
```

If `pthread library` is needed, also add it in the cmake file.
This worked for me. Got the solution from https://forum.anope.org